# How do I resolve utf Oracle export error?

Tags: oracle, export

When I try to export a user from oracle 9i following error is displayed:

> Export done in we8mswin1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR
>   Character set Server uses WE8ISO8859P1 character set (possible charset
>   Conversion).

Note: I am trying to export data from Linux based oracle by accessing server on Windows xp.

Comment: There is an answer for the same question exists here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/oracle-db-export-possible-charset-conversion-if-nls-lang-not-set

Comment: It is not my answer senerio is Linux is oracle server and xp is also oracle server I am trying to export data from Linux oracle server

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, this is NOT an error, it is a message just telling you that your session's character set is different from the database's character set, so expdp did convert between the two. So, either that's ok for you, or you change your session's character set (NLS_LANG), and redo the expdp.

Comment: To which character set should I change what will be command over win xp

Comment: Use the WEISO8895P1, same as the DB.